# OpenGL make display list faster

Tags: c++, performance, opengl, displaylist

I am programing a OBJ model loader. I did several experiment on a very massive model. The loading it self into a variables takes only 5 millisecond and the display list part takes 110 millisecond. I have checked if I do something wrong and it appears to be that 90 millisecond is the time that OpenGL do some functions like glBegin and glNewList and stuff like that. 90 millisecond is too long for me. Is there any way to accelerate this part? Or should I use different OpenGL loading as VBO?

Comment: Come on, *display lists*? In 2014? Dump that stuff and start using modern OpenGL, VBOs are just the start to get any decent performance.

Comment: You SHOULD use a different type of loading like http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_vbo.html

Comment: @peppe: Display lists are actually still used in other modern APIs. In fact, D3D11 sort of re-introduced them when it pushed for its multi-threading architecture (via [Deferred Rendering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476892(v=vs.85).aspx) and command buffers). We might see them come back to GL too; to a very limited extent, indirect drawing/compute dispatch is the closest thing we (in the GL world) have to modern display lists. Nevertheless, what GL currently calls display lists should be avoided.

Comment: I was specifically talking about **display lists**, not [`GL_ARB_draw_indirect`](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/draw_indirect.txt). That's usually called multi-draw-indirect.

Comment: @peppe: No it is ***not***, there is a separate extension: [`GL_ARB_multi_draw_indirect`](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/multi_draw_indirect.txt) that is *"usually called multi-draw-indirect"*. And I was specifically telling you that **display lists** are still used on consoles and other APIs in 2014 and that OpenGL may re-adopt them in the form of command buffers (draw indirect is a move in that direction). There is nothing fundamentally wrong with display lists in fact used correctly they improve performance, they are just badly implemented in their current GL form.

Comment: Sorry, of course, I linked the wrong extension. I totally agree with you. I'm still referring to the current form of display lists, the ones nobody should use.

Comment: It's not display lists that's the problem. It's immediate mode rendering (`glBegin`/`glEnd`). Even in a display list, it simply isn't performant. Unfortunately it seems like 'display lists'  seems to imply 'display lists and immediate mode rendering' in the OpenGL world, which is a shame.